# drop down lists in xcode

Tags: iphone, uikit, ip

Ive got a button in a UICell. I want a list(a table view like view to be precise) to dropdown when the user touches the button and dissappear when he touches it again.Googling didnt get me any solutions:-(

Any suggestions on sites to refer would also be appreciated..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing quite like what you want in UIKit. I would recommend building the sample "UICatalog" application and playing around with it to see if anything does what you need. If it does not, you will need to create your own control.

Comment: im thinking of creating  tableview and making it visible on button touch.Not sure how practical it would be